# overflow-x: scroll doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I am confused why this doesn't work. I'm trying to achieve horizontal scrolling inside `div.queue-wrapper`, so `div.queue-month` don't fall down one after another if there is not enough space (which is what they do at the moment).

**HTML**

```
        <div class="queue-container">
            <div class="queue-wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="queue-month">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="queue-month">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="queue-month">
                    3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- .queue-container -->
```

**CSS**

```
.queue-container {
    height: 260px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.queue-wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
}

.queue-month {
    width: 385px;
    float: left;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1rLkfjr/) example

I'm using bootstrap 3, but as it doesn't work in fiddle I assume it has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: There is nothing to scroll

Comment: @MirkoBrombin no change in that fiddle. But shouldn't it scroll because the .queue-month divs have fixed width that overflows one of the .queue-wrapper?

Comment: Sorry mistake, check my answer.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g1rLkfjr/4/

Comment: You can use css property overflow-x:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use white-space to be nowrap and use inline-block display instead of float:

```css
.queue-container {
    height: 260px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.queue-wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;/*changed from scroll*/
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;/*using nowrap*/
}

.queue-month {
    width: 385px;
    display: inline-block;/*instead of float:left;*/
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!-- Dragable queue section -->
        <div class="queue-container">
            <div class="queue-wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="queue-month">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="queue-month">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="queue-month">
                    3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- .queue-container -->
```

Comment: There's no long text so it would scroll.

Comment: if the container have more than its space then only it will scroll.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to make it scroll if .queue-month divs don't have enough space to be horizontally positioned one after another.

Comment: As at the moment they simply fall one after another.

Comment: I just understood your question. wait.

Answer (score 2):

You do not give nothing to scroll, try this:

**CSS**

```
.queue-container {
    height: 260px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.queue-wrapper {
  background: yellow;
  width: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.queue-month {
  width: 385px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-table;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g1rLkfjr/2/